# How to calculate the residue of this function

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Consider a function $$f(x)=\frac{1}{(x-1)^\alpha (x+1)^\alpha}$$ where $\alpha$ is a positive small number (not necessary to be an integer). How to calculate the residue at $x=1$?

Comment: If $\alpha$ is not an integer, $f$ is not analytic in a punctured neighborhood of $x=1$ (due to branching), so the residue is not defined.

Comment: @StefanBöttner Thanks!

Comment: @Weaam Thank you for providing the link, it solves my question.